# Como ter a função de isset usando $queryString no php

Tags: php, html, querystring

Tenho um código em ***php*** que tem a função de pegar o parâmetro `?capa=` com `parse_str`

```
<?php 
$url = parse_url($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
parse_str($url["query"],$queryString);?>
```

Esse e o código dele: `<?php echo $queryString["capa"] ?>`

mas como fazer a função isset do `$_GET` no `$queryString`

Ou seja, com o $_GET eu fazia assim: `$largura = isset($_GET ["largura"])?$_GET ["largura"]:"100%";` ou seja se não tivesse um valor em `?largura=` receberia 100%.

**como fazer dessa outra forma uma vez que a query string é interpretada com `parse_str` ?**

Comment: Não consegui perceber o problema. `$largura = isset($_GET ["largura"])?$_GET ["largura"]:"100%";` não funciona ?

Comment: Sim funciona, mas isso usando $_GET, no meu caso eu quero fazer usando `<?php echo $queryString["capa"] ?>`

Comment: Mas `$queryString` é um array ? Ou você quer ir buscar `capa` também aos parametros do `$_GET` ? `$capa = isset($_GET["capa"]) ? $_GET["capa"] : "outro_valor_que_dê_jeito";` ? A sua questão está confusa.

Comment: Eu isso pra pegar as informações que vem de um site com referencia: `<?php $url = parse_url($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);parse_str($url["query"],$queryString);?>` assim eu eu pego a referencia capa `<?php echo $queryString["capa"] ?>` mas e se caso eu não tiver uma capa, como colocar uma padrão ? e isso que tento falar..

Comment: Tudo isso que está a utilizar para interpretar os valores é relevante e deve estar na pergunta, caso contrário ela não fica clara o suficiente. Acrescente essas informações à pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que indicou nos comentários está a utilizar `parse_url` e `parse_str` para obter os parametros da query string de um determinado url. Se consultar a documentação vê que [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-str.php) lhe devolve um array com chave e valor para cada parametro na query string.

Se quer saber se não existe para atribuir um valor por defeito pode utilizar o `isset` na mesma, consultando pela chave que deseja:

```
$capa = isset($queryString["capa"]) ? $queryString["capa"] : "100%";
```

Ou até mesmo direto no `echo`:

```
<?php echo isset($queryString["capa"]) ? $queryString["capa"] : "100%"; ?>
```

Pode até utilizar o [*null coalescing operator*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)(Operador de coalescência nula) para fazer o mesmo, se estiver a correr na versão 7 do php:

```
$capa = $queryString["capa"] ?? "100%";
```

E

```
<?php echo $queryString["capa"] ?? "100%"; ?>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado! me ajudou! e não sabia que era tão simples assim.